# Saving mongoose schema without creating a new schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using the following code, which is also working

```
'use strict';

const Profile = require('../database/shemas/profileSchema');
const ProfileHelper = require('../helpers/profileHelper');
const logger = require('../utils/logger');

const createUpdateProfile = (req, res) => {
    //Fillout Schema
    let uuid = req.user.identities[0].id;
    let provider = req.user.identities[0].provider;
    let email = req.user.email;
    let firstName = req.user.name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    let lastName = req.user.name.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
    let pictureUrl = req.user.picture;
    let profileToSafe = new Profile({
        uuid,
        provider,
        email,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        pictureUrl
    });
    //createUpdate
    if (!!!uuid) {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid argument supplied');
    } else {
        Profile.findOne({ uuid }).then(object => {
            if (object !== null) {
                var upsertData = profileToSafe.toObject();
                delete upsertData._id;
                delete upsertData.uuid;
                delete upsertData.provider;
                Profile.update({ uuid }, upsertData, { upsert: true }, function (err, raw) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('callback -> err', err);
                    }
                    console.log('callback -> raw', raw);
                    res.status(200).send('Successful operation');
                });
            } else {
                profileToSafe.save();
                res.status(200).send('Successful operation');
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is my schema

```
'use strict';

// Mongoose schema definitions
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Profile Schema
const profileSchema = new Schema({
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    birthday: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    pictureUrl: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    }, // Later we can add a default image for users who use cloud directory login
    onboardingDone: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    }
}, {
        timestamps: true, // Add CreatedAt and updatedAt fields automatically
        strict: 'throw'
    });

const Profile = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema);

module.exports = Profile
```

But the trick was, that I needed to delete the id

```
    delete upsertData._id;
```

A colleague persists that this is due wrong usage of

```
    let profileToSafe = new Profile({ ...
```

I tried different variations but none of them worked. Is there really another (more) correct way of doing what I want?

Edit: I did what @Sridhar suggested but now I'm running into a problem with the timestamp. Even when I delete it from the schema.

Comment: Why not just use of `update` ? You already precised the `upsert: true`. Do not use of `findOne`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT thanks for the tip. I could have get rid of fineOne() but still I got the ID error

Comment: You are querying by `uuid` value. If the profile exists, update it with additional value. If it doesn't, create a new profile. Is this what you're trying to do here?

Comment: @Sridhar correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoose's [findOneAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate) with `upsert:true` option.

> Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the callback.

**Options**

> upsert: bool - creates the object if it doesn't exist. defaults to false.

Making those changes to your code

```
'use strict';

const Profile = require('../database/shemas/profileSchema');
const ProfileHelper = require('../helpers/profileHelper');
const logger = require('../utils/logger');

const createUpdateProfile = (req, res) => {

  const uuid = req.user.identities[0].id;
  const provider = req.user.identities[0].provider;

  const email = req.user.email;

  const firstName = req.user.name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
  const lastName = req.user.name.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
  const pictureUrl = req.user.picture;

  if (!uuid) {
    return res.status(400).send('Invalid argument supplied');
  }

  Profile.findOneAndUpdate({
    uuid
  }, {
    provider,
    email,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    pictureUrl,
    $setOnInsert: {
      createdAt: Date.now()
    },
    updatedAt: Date.now()
  }, {
    upsert: true
  }).then(() => {
    res.status(200).send('Successful operation');
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('callback -> err', err);
    // You can send appropriate response here
  });

}
```

Comment: As you edited his code, please replace the inaccurate `let` by `const`

Comment: Also you can use `shorthand` notation for all the data in the json

Comment: Thank you! But Now I have a problem with the timestamp. I defined the following in the schema: {
        timestamps: true, // Add CreatedAt and updatedAt fields automatically
        strict: 'throw'
    }

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Thanks for suggesting. Updated my answer

Comment: @Sridhar I added my schema. Running into problems with the timestamp it seems. Even when I delete it from the schema, which is very weird. TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `timestamps`

Comment: @Sridhar there is a case sensitive type for CreateAt. I Fixed it but still I got the same error: TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `timestamps`

Comment: @KiSa87 Are you sure, you're using mongoose > 4.0?

Comment: @Sridhar  yes, "mongoose": "5.0.9", I also tried setting the name of timestamp but it did not helped either

Comment: @Sridhar it was a dumb side effect, what you described works well. Big sorry and thanks!

Comment: @KiSa87 Glad that it worked for you. Could you please accept the answer :)

Comment: @Sridhar sorry, did not know I can do this already. Did so. Thanks again :)